# Directed colimit of fully faithful functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, adjoint-functors

Suppose that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have a category $\mathcal{C}_n$ and a fully faithful functor $F_n:\mathcal{C}_n\hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}_{n+1}$. My question is whether fully faithful functors are preserved under taking the colimit in the following sense: is the canonical functor for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\mathcal{C}_n\to \mbox{colim} (\mathcal{C}_0\xrightarrow{F_0}\mathcal{C}_1\xrightarrow{F_1}\mathcal{C}_2\xrightarrow{F_2}\cdots )$$
also fully faithful? And why?

My intuition says yes, and I have been trying to show this through the universal property, but I didn't manage to find a convenient way to use it. Maybe the method should be to explicitely describe the colimit in $\mbox{Cat}$.

I have asked myself the above question in order to determine if the unit of an adjunction between subcategories of $\mbox{Cat}$ is objectwise a fully faithful functor. In the particular case I have encountered, the right adjoint is an inclusion, while the left adjoint involves a colimit as above, this is why I am trying to prove full faithfulness by hand. Is there a more general result giving conditions for having the unit which is objectwise a fully faithful functor, as we do when we characterise when the unit of an adjunction is objectwise a mono?

Answer (score 5):

Both objects and morphisms in the colimit are given by the same colimit in the category of sets, which is to say that an object is an equivalence class of objects $\varphi=[c]$ with $c$ in some $\mathcal C_n$ and two objects are equivalent if and only if they're sent to the same object of some $\mathcal C_m$ in the diagram. The analogous description holds for morphisms, in that every map $\varphi\to \varphi'$ is represented by a map $f:c\to c'$ in some $\mathcal C_n$ and two such representations are equal in the colimit if and only if they become equal in some $\mathcal C_m.$ So if some two parallel maps in some $\mathcal C_n$ become equal in the colimit then they must become equal in some $\mathcal C_m,$ and therefore in $\mathcal C_n$ itself, and the functor at issue is faithful; if objects $\varphi,\varphi'$ of the colimit are represented by $c,c'$ in $\mathcal C_n$ and we have a map $\gamma:\varphi\to \varphi',$ then it is represented by $g:d\to d'$ in some $\mathcal C_m.$ Since $c,d$ and $c',d'$ are equivalent, they are equated in some $\mathcal C_p,$ so we can assume $\gamma$ is represented by a map bettween the images of $c,c'$ in some $\mathcal C_p.$ But then by fullness of $\mathcal C_n\to \mathcal C_p,$ we are done.

As you can see, the argument isn't entirely trivial here, but you should have a very strong instinct that most nice finitary properties are preserved by directed colimits in nice categories. More formally, filtered colimits (such as directed colimits) commute with finite limits in locally finitely presentable categories, which are very common. This particular case is slightly trickier since "fully faithful" is a 2-categorical condition, not an ordinary categorical one, but you could still give a fancy proof of this claim by observing that fully faithfulness can be described in terms of 2-categorical finite limits.

Comment: You actually *should not* fall under the impression that filtered colimits (or even direct sums) preserve any "nice finitary properties" in "nice categories", because the notion of "nice" is heavily influenced by user experience (usually misconceptions come from categories of modules over a ring). One of the nicest possible ones — category of modules over an adjunction monad — very seldom has exact filtered colimits; more or less, you need finite presentability. Localisations of finitely presented categories are very rarely finitely presentable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know this explicit characterisation of colimits, which makes the answer clear. Do you suggest a reference for learning more about colimits in $\mbox{Cat}$?

Comment: @DenisT Of course this all depends on what you think of as “nice”.

Answer (score 1):

See **Colimits of accessible categories** by *Paré and Rosicky*.